# Regular Expression split with white spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string as mentioned below.

> Test[0] = Value1 Test1[0] = Value2 Test3[0] = Value3....etc.,

I want to use Regular Expression to separate them as below

```
Test[0] = Value1
Test1[0] = Value2
Test3[0] = Value3
```

Can you please give me some regular expression to split them one line string into multiple lines?

Please let me know if you need more clarification on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "Test[0] = Value1 Test1[0] = Value2 Test3[0] = Value3";
String result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!=)\s(?!=)", "\r\n");
```

The regular expression `(?<!=)\s(?!=)` is searching for a whitespace character *(the `\s`, maybe you want to replace this with a single space , because `\s` contains also newline characters.)* that has no `=` before or after it and replaces it with `\r\n`.

This produces for your example the result you expect.

**Update:**

instead of guessing around with the replacement sequence for newline, there is a nice shortcut in `.net` to get the newline of the current system: `Environment.NewLine`

so change the code to:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!=)\s(?!=)", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific in what you allow before or after the newline. What you can do if there must be numbers or letters on each side (here as opposed to an `=` or `]`) of a space, is this search and replace:

```
s/([\d\w])\s([\d\w])/\1\n\2/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

regex expression:

```
(Test[\d]*\[[\d]+\])\s*\=\s*(\w+)\s*
```

replace expression(only an example):

```
$1 = $2 + chr(13)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var results = Regex.Matches("Test[0] = Value1 Test1[0] = Value2 Test3[0] = Value3", @"[^\s]+\s*=\s*[^\s]+")
            .OfType<Match>()
            .Select(item => item.Value)
            .ToArray();
```

This will match the x = y where x and y can be anything except whitespace characters.